# Express the number of ordered sets of positive integers whose sum is $n$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $q(n)$ denote the number of **ordered** sets of positive integers whose sum is $n$. Calculate $q(n)$ using a **direct** counting argument. I really don't quite understand the rules. What does "ordered" really stand for here? After that, I am asked to look at unordered sets. Am I allowed to use the same number more than once? I am really confused here, and the calculation seem to lead me nowhere solid. I would appreciate any outlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the likely meaning for "ordered" and "unordered," in the form of an example, with $n=4$:

Ordered sets summing to $4$:

$$\begin{align}
&1+1+1+1\\
&2+1+1,\quad 1+2+1,\quad 1+1+2\\
&2+2\\
&3+1,\quad1+3\\
&4
\end{align}$$

(so $q(4)=8$).

Unordered sets summing to $4$:

$$\begin{align}
&1+1+1+1\\
&2+1+1\\
&2+2\\
&3+1\\
&4
\end{align}$$

(so $p(4)=5$, if we let $p(n)$ denote the number of unordered sets of positive integers whose sum in $n$).

Note that nothing here is actually a "set" in the usual mathematical sense of the word. Nor do the adjectives "ordered" and "unordered" look like they've been affixed correctly:  the "unordered" sets have things nicely ordered (from largest to smallest in each sum), whereas the "ordered" sets seem to allow things to be out of order!  Nonetheless I'm willing to bet that this is what's meant by the terminology here.  If it is, and if you need further help, I (or someone else) will gladly provide it.

Comment: So, "ordered" means "specific"?
Excuse my lacking sense of rationality. I have arrived at a point where I no longer distinguished between "ordered" and "non-decreasing" or monotone.

Comment: It was translated, and I believe my teacher, writing the notes, used the wrong term (really wasting my time).

Comment: @Meitar, "ordered" here means that the (linear) order in which summands appear matters, which is why $3+1$ and $1+3$ each count once.  You can think of "ordered" as placing things in a row, and "unordered" as putting them in a bag.

Comment: Okay, I have arrived at $2^{n-1}$ using recurrence. The examples are consistent so far. Do you know if this is correct?

Comment: @Meitar, yes, very good!  You can find confirmation -- and some different terminology -- at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) .  Be sure also to click on the link to "partitions" for the unordered case (where there is no such nice, simple formula).

Comment: Thank you, it was very educating.

Comment: Recurrence is fine, but you were asked for a DIRECT counting argument. Did you find it? HINT: imagine you write $n$ copies of the number $1$, from left to right, in a single row. BETWEEN each consecutive $1$'s, mark a vertical bar, which can be either solid red or it can be made invisible. Can you see a direct connection between all the possible choices (combinations) of solid red bars, on the one hand (and how many such choices are there?), and on the other hand the different ways of writing $n$ as an ordered sum of positive integers?