# Number of ordered sets of positive integers, whose sum is n

Tags: combinatorics

A very similar question has already been asked ([Express the number of ordered sets of positive integers whose sum is $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719060/express-the-number-of-ordered-sets-of-positive-integers-whose-sum-is-n)), but mine is a little different.

I am trying to count how many ordered **sets** of positive integers sum up to n. I need to find a direct counting argument to support my answer. The number I am looking for is defiend by:
$$ q(n):=\left |  {{{\left \{ {(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)|k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and }  \sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i=n \text{ and } \left | {\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} {\left \{ a_i \right \}}} \right |=k} \right \}}}}\right | $$
Because the sets are ordered, if $n=5$, then each of $2+3$ and $3+2$ is counted seperately. However, because we count **sets**, repetitions are not allowed, so $1+1+3$ is not counted.

I am struggling with this problem for quite a long time, and have not managed to find an answer... I'd appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** By "ordered set" I mean sequence with no repetations.

Comment: You can prevent text from being italicized (and incorrectly spaced) in equations by enclosing it in `\text{...}`.

Comment: There's no such thing as an ordered set. What you mean is called a composition of $n$ with distinct parts.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A032020](http://oeis.org/A032020). Apparently there's no closed form, but the entry has some links and provides the generating function.